# Is there a way to refresh webView every x seconds?

Tags: java, android, webview

Now I have this function for reload webView:

```
    public void reloadWebView() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView.reload();
            }
        }, 5000);}
```

And it is called on *onCreate* function

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        reloadWebView();


    }
```

The function works but it only runs once

Comment: Use CountDownTimer to update webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to solve as long as the `Activity` is running in foreground:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 public void reloadWebView() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.reload();
            reloadWebView();
        }
    }, 5000);}
```

Note that handler is now a field, out of `reloadWebView()`.
Now call it in your `onCreate()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    reloadWebView();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to update your webview after x seconds

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    webView.reload();
   //here you can have your logic to reload webview
}

public void onFinish() {
    // hide progress bar if any
  }

}.start();
```